# Can I install SQL Server 2014 Express and Visual Studio 2013 Web on Windows Server 2008 R2 sp2?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2008

I would like to know if it's possible to install both SQL Server 2014 Express and Visual Studio 2013 Web on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2 machine, and if so, what are the requirements, like what version of the .NET framework should I install given the possibility.

I hope someone can clarify this, thanks.

Comment: The operating system requirements for Microsoft products are *easily* found by searching for the products on the Microsoft site.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding SQL Server Express 2014:**
Yes you can install it on Server 2008 R2 SP2. The requirements can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx)

**Regarding Visual Studio 2013 Web:**
Yes this is also possible. The requirements can be seen at [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks you for you answer and links provided.

Answer (score 1):

Installing this is possible, just like the other post says. I have these version installed on a machine however and they dont seem to "play nice". VS 13 express web has some issues recognizing the database in this set up. Might/should be a temporary bug and might already be fixed in the latest SQL server 2014, just thought I would share.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will definitely take note.